# How to connect from Remix to Kovan testnet?

Tags: testnets, remix, kovan

In Remix, there is a Contracts tab, where I can choose the "Execution environment". When I choose "Web3 Provider", I am asked to provide the "Web3 provider endpoint". What should I write there in order to connect to the public Kovan testnet?

<sub>(I hope the question makes sense... I am entirely new to Ether)</sub>

Answer (score 2):

run  parity with `parity --chain kovan`. and then in your endpoint provide http://localhost:8545 or http://127.0.0.1:8545

8545 is the RPC port

Comment: I have problems installing Parity. Isn't there a way to connect to Kovan testnet without installing a software?  Don't they have a "Web3 provider endpoint"?

Comment: As i know parity is the only client who can connect you to kovan.

Answer (score 0):

Download and use the chrome extension called `Matamask` and connect your account into. (if you haven't done yet)

then click on `Show/Hide test networks`

[image]

Then turn the switch ON

[image]

Then change the network to Kaven in Metamask

[image]

Then in `Remix` change the `Environment` to `Injected Web3`

[image]

The Metamask will popup and want you to connect the Remix to it. just follow the steps. (if it didn't change to Injected Web3 you should wait for a few moments and if still didn't change or you are living in Iran use a VPN and try again)

Congrats you have connected your Remix to Kovan testnet.